# Get Excel HyperLink Cell String

Tags: c#, excel, hyperlink

I'm trying to get the hyperlink string from an Excel cell using the excel data reader library in C#, but retrieving the cell and calling the ToString method didn't work.

This is my code so far:

```
using (var stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)){
      
      using var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);
      var result = reader.AsDataSet();

      DataTable table = result.Tables[0];

      bool jumpCol = true; // Avoid first lane
      foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
      {
          if (jumpCol)
          {
             jumpCol = false;
             continue;
          }
     }

     PlateImage = row[6].ToString(); //This returns 0
```

I just need the hyperlink string:

```
=HYPERLINK("thisString.jpg")
```

Any ideas? Any library that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Install Free Spire.XLS from NuGet:
**Install-Package FreeSpire.XLS**

Next, you can read the hyperlinks from Excel with the following code:

```
using Spire.Xls;
using System;
namespace RetrieveHyperlink
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Workbook wb = new Workbook();
            wb.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Hyperlinks.xlsx");

            Worksheet sheet = wb.Worksheets[0];
            foreach (var item in sheet.HyperLinks)
            {
                string address = item.Address;
                CellRange range = item.Range;
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Cell[{0},{1}] contains URL: {2}", range.Row, range.Column, address));
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the free version has a limitation of 5 sheets and 200 rows per sheet for **.xls** file format.